# Find the significance of a variable in a linear model when another correlated variable has a stronger opposite effect

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, linear-model, inference

I have a linear model $Y = AX_1 + BX_2 + e$ where $e$ is noise, $Y$ is the dependent variable, $A$ & $B$ are coefficients, and $X_1$ & $X_2$ are variables.

Suppose that we know in the real world $A$ is the opposite sign of $B$ (say $A$ is negative and $B$ is positive) and $X_2$ has a larger impact on $Y$ than $X_1$. Also, suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are highly correlated, such that when we create a linear model of $Y = AX_1 + e$ it shows that $A$ is positive, not because that is the true relation ship between $X_1$ and $Y$, but only because $X_2$ has a stronger effect on $Y$ than $X_1$, and high values of $X_1$ are associated with high values of $X_2$.

If my basic linear model $Y = AX_1 + BX_2 + e$ is showing $A$ and $B$ to both be positive (when we know $A$'s sign should be negative) what are some other strategies for teasing out $X_1$'s true relationship to $Y$ given the correlation?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "basic linear model" at the end.  Are you referring to a *least squares fit* of the model to the data?  If so, you appear to describe a situation where the data conflict with your assumptions about the signs of $A$ and $B$.  That's an extremely general problem with loads of answers ranging from "change your theory" to "collect more data" to "ignore the data altogether."  Is there anything else you can tell us that would suggest what kind of answer might be appropriate in your case?

Comment: Yes, by basic linear model I am referring to least squares regression. Unfortunately, the data is somewhat high tailed (not normal) and not linear, so I am assuming that is why some of my assumptions are appearing to be violated. I am trying to figure out other ways of pulling out out significance. Perhaps this question is too general for it to be answerable, if so I apologize.